# Rails.cache fails after being idle for some minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

Last week we migrated our app to Ruby 3.2.2 and Rails 7.0.4.3. Since then, we've started getting errors when executing any commands that need to access Redis. This issue only occurs in production. The app is on Heroku, and it's running the latest version of Redis available, 7.0.11.

It seems like Rails is losing connection with Redis, it fails on the first try, but if you try again, it passes.

```
Rails.cache.stats
# => app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.14.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:101:in `rescue in read` EOFError (Redis::ConnectionError)
# => app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.14.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:101:in `rescue in read` EOFError (RedisClient::ConnectionError)
# => app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.14.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection/buffered_io.rb:145:in `block in fill_buffer': EOFError (EOFError)
Rails.cache.stats
# => {
"redis_version"=>"7.0.11",
"redis_git_sha1"=>...
}
```

However, if you run it again after a few minutes (5 maybe?) without running anything, it'll fail again and then pass on the next try.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

I tried to use rescue on the places where we are reading/writing to the cache, but it's not working.

UPDATE: Thanks, Tadman. It was a Heroku issue. It was dropping idle connections after 5 minutes. This seems to be the default behaviour, though. The timeout setting was probably overwritten when we updated Redis to its latest version, which was done at the same time as the Rails upgrade. So, if someone is having the same issue, the solution that worked for me was to disable timeout for the Redis connection.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is my first post and I didn't know about the images. I edited it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: It could be your Redis instance is being shut down and has to quickly start up when poked. This seems like a Heroku issue.